# Binding to ObservableCollection with MVVM Light

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding, mvvm-light, observablecollection

I have a `MainViewModel` that contains a reference to an `ObservableCollection`:

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> ListOfPeople
{
    get
    {
        return MyClass.BaseCollection;
    }
}
```

`BaseCollection` is also an instance of `ObservableCollection<SomeClass>`. `ListOfPeople` is bound to a `ListBox` control on the second page - the application starts with the first page, initiates the download process to populate `BaseCollection` and switches to the second page while the download is still in progress.

The problem is that when the binding occurs, `BaseCollection` is null and therefore the `ListBox` is not populated. However, even when the download process finishes, the ListBox still remains empty. I am assuming this is happening because BaseCollection isn't notifying the proper instance about existing changes to the collection, but I am not sure.

`BaseCollection` has items inside it - I confirmed it.

Any suggestions on how I can work around the issue? Anyone here binding to an ObservableCollection via MVVM Light just like I showed above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you donot want to instantiate an empty ListOfPeople in the constructor and use this instance for database-loading you have to do this:

After loading of `ListOfPeople` is completed, your `MainViewModel` must call `RaisePropertyChanged("ListOfPeople");` to tell the view that the data has changed.

Background: Thanks to ObservableCollection `MyClass.BaseCollection.Add()` updates the gui. As soon as `MyClass.BaseCollection = new Obser...` is called there is no more update of the gui since the gui holds a reference to the old contend of `MyClass.BaseCollection`. mvvm-light-RaisePropertyChanged() tells the gui to update its reference to a new collection

Comment: Actually worked like a charm - after all there was a MVVM Light nuance there. Thanks!

Comment: On the flip side, user will have to wait for a while until any item appears in the ListBox. Also, why would you use ObservableCollection then? Even using a simple List<> and doing RaisePropertyChanged(..) when you are done with downloading will also do the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't worked on MVVM Light, so sorry if there is something specific about it that i am missing.

Looking at your implementation,

```
public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> ListOfPeople
{
    get
    {
        return MyClass.BaseCollection;
    }
}
```

This code should work, and the control which is binded to this source should get propert updated without being concerned about the actual source where the instance of observable is created.

Thus, the only possible problem here could be that your MyBase.BaseCollection is null in the begining. So, if you avoid that situation and create an empty collection where you have declared this observable item, and then trigger your downloading process the way it is, then everything should work fine.

Hope this would be of help.

Comment: I agree with @Amby's answer, just need to instantiate the BaseCollection at the MyClass constuctor would solve this. And MVVMLight has nothing to do here with this binding scenario.

Comment: The MVVM Light was there for reference purposes - just making sure there are no implementation nuances. The thing is - MyClass is static, which is fine - there is a static constructor and I can initialize the collection before switching to the second page (and thus binding). At the beginning the collection is indeed null, but even with initialization it doesn't seem to have any effect on it whatsoever.