# Delayed Loading of BitmapImage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, bitmapimage

I'm trying to load BitmapImages in a ListBox in Windows Phone 8 and seeing strange behavious. The first time the page is displayed, the ListBox appears empty, but if I go back, then back to the page the images load. To me it seems as though the images aren't being loaded when they need to be. This is the code I'm using (via a converter):

```
        BitmapImage img = null;
        StreamResourceInfo res = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/MyAssembly;component/Resource/images/myimage.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Stream s = res.Stream;
        using (s) {
            img= new BitmapImage();
            img.SetSource(s);
        }
        img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.None;
```

I've tried experimenting with the create options to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it could be something with the view not being refreshed after the source is set.  You load an empty list box.  then load all the images. nothing shows arrggh!  but when you come back to the page, magic! they are all there because the entire view is redrawn (now with the image sources).  if you kill the app before you go back to it, you should see an empty list box again since the sources must be reset.  I'm not sure how this works in windows 8 but you should be able to call something like listbox.RefreshView() to force it to redraw itself.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I added calls to `lstIcon.UpdateLayout();` and `lstIcon.GetBindingExpression(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty).UpdateSource();` after the Page_Loaded event, but still no dice.

Answer (score 0):

I actually needed to call `RaisePropertyChanged` on the property in my ViewModel to force the update, [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280624/binding-to-observablecollection-with-mvvm-light) but your answer pointed me in the right direction. Thanks @teabaggs.

The bizarre thing is, this worked when I had a Pivot control as the root element, but switching to a Panorama must have changed the event order.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
img.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.BackGround;

and assign in 
`private void BitmapImage_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            BitmapImage img = new BitmapImage();
            img.UriSource = new Uri("Your local Image", UriKind.Relative);
        }`
Your local image.
Anyways image will take time in being rendered, this is best and fastest method i have found till now